# Mouse and keyboard "freeze" for no reason

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze, lag, unresponsive

I have a weird bug on window.

Randomly wired my mouse and keyboard stop responding and after 1-2 sec it works again.
It happen every 5-10 min or so it is very random.

What is weird is that if while my keyboard is not responding I press some key the key will buffer until the keyboard start working again, same thing with the mouse I think, but it is harder to see.

I just bought a new mouse to try to solve the problem, but it does nothing.

I tried to reinstall the mouse and keyboard drive, but it changes nothing.

Furthermore, I would check if there is a program that could cause that, but I have no idea where to start.

How could I diagnose the problem and where should I start looking to fix the issue.

If nothing work I will do a fresh window install

Comment: Are you mouse and keyboard plugged in directly to the computer or a hub? Are they wired or cable?

Comment: Yes they are wired and plug in the motherboard. I just thought of trying changing port.

Comment: Yes, when troubleshooting devices, changing ports is always a good way to see if that is part of the issue. Please let us know if that changes anything,

Comment: with John Answer it seem to work. I also change usb port. I dont think it was the port because the keyboard and the mouse was having "Freeze"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a reason. There could be driver issues, operating system damage, or profile damage. It might take considerable time to find the exact cause, if it can be found.

Try the following:

**(1) Windows Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

(If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.)

Use the option to Keep Everything.

A Repair Install will normally update drivers also.

**(2) Repair Keep Everything fails to solve the issue**

Something more serious has occurred (including a damaged User Profile). Whichever, the best solution now is to back everything up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I seem to work. If finally it is not working I will report back. Thanks